# Downloading from OneDrive with Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, onedrive

I need help with scraping from OneDrive.
I need to click download button from this page:
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=6C890C686174A5C6&id=6C890C686174A5C6%212518&parId=root&action=defaultclick
Everytime I try XPATH it keeps changing and changing and I dont know more what to do.
I tried CSS and still not working...

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://login.live.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]').send_keys("xxxxxx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]').send_keys("xxxxxx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
driver.get("https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=6C890C686174A5C6&id=6C890C686174A5C6%212518&parId=root&action=defaultclick")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("od-Button od-ButtonBarCommand od-ButtonBarCommand--button").click()
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems the id is changing frequently. So, try to write a relevant XPath to that element without using id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I tried and still doesn't work... <button class="od-Button od-ButtonBarCommand od-ButtonBarCommand--button" data-bind="attr:{title:command.tooltip},css:{'is-disabled':command.isDisabled,'is-focused':command.focused,'od-Button--primary':isPrimary},hasFocus:command.isActive,disable:command.isDisabled,click:command.onClick.bind(command)"><!--ko if:command.icon--><!--/ko--><!--ko if:command.iconUrl--><!--/ko--><!--ko if:command.isLabelVisible--><span class="od-Button-label od-ButtonBarCommand-label" data-bind="text:command.label">Download</span><!--/ko--></button>